# How to cerate unique link for each uuid in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to generat ethe unique link for each uuid which are into database but getting below error -

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: id`

I had tried below code

view.py

```
def Insert_Record(request, uid):
    obj_uid = Get_Customer_ID.objects.get(slug=uid) or id=uid
```

url.py

```
path('form/<str:id>/<slug:uid>', views.Insert_Record),
```

model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False


class Get_Customer_ID(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "TABLE_NAME"
```

DB - Table Format - UUID is the first column which is primary key.

Comment: How does your model look like?

Comment: @GCMeccariello, Please check above question, edited now

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two arguments to the path `id` and `uid`.
Therefore you should get them both into your function. But it seems that the model does not contain a field named `uid`.

view.py:

```
def Insert_Record(request, id):
    obj_uid = Product.objects.get(id=id)
```

urls.py:

```
path('form/<int:id>', views.Insert_Record), # make sure to select 'int' for id
```

In case you have more fields in your model, for example a name field you could write something like:

view.py:

```
def Insert_Record(request, id, name):
    obj_uid = Product.objects.get(id=id) 
    # do something with 'name'
```

urls.py:

```
path('form/<int:id>/<str:name>', views.Insert_Record),
```

Comment: I tried same but my id is uuid like `6ddaef86-122e-4499-a1ae-a300cbbf8fae`.

Comment: what is your error?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The issue is that you use `Get_Customer_ID.objects.get(slug=uid)` instead if `id=uid`. And need to change the URL also, because it expects 2 path parameters, and you only need 1.

So, we would have something like this:

view.py

```
def Insert_Record(request, uid):
    obj_uid = Product.objects.get(id=uid)
```

urls.py

```
path('form/<slug:uid>', views.Insert_Record),
```